# Getting started with OpenGL ES 2.0 on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

This is a very specific questions about the steps necessary to Build a simple OpenGL ES 2.0 program on the Windows platform.  The environment is Visual Studio with unmanaged C++.

I go to the Khronos.org site and, frankly, find it a bit opaque because it reads like something written by a standards body.  I don't want to download a "reference" or a "specification", etc.

All I'm looking for are the links and steps to get me from A to B.  In other words, "Download these files or run this setup at this URL.  Create a new Visual studio project with references to these libraries.  Include this header file."

Again, I'm interested in ES 2.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After alot of digging around for the same thing. I found an emulator for openGL es 2 from PowerVR: http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/index.asp

The AMD one linked above is no longer available or supported.

Comment: This link throws a 404 now too

Answer (score 13):

I have been using googles [Angle Project](http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/).  It converts opengles 2.0 to DirectX 9 calls for win32.  It works fairly well and even has quite a few examples.  Its also the BSD licence so anything you make you can use the source for your own projects.

Comment: I like converter more than Emulation.

Comment: You need to build from source code using VC2015, changing the version of Directx (default value is DX11)... so you need at least Windows 7.

Answer (score 9):

AMD bundle OpenGL ES with their normal Catalyst drivers (for Win & Lin).

You just need to use EGL to get OpenGL ES context! (And have to use headers/includes from AMD OpenGL ES SDK).

- AMD users already have everything they need to run your app.
- Every doc about EGL and OGL ES is valid.
- It work on AMD only.

PS Yes it is different from OLD/DEPRECATED OpenGL ES **emulator**. Because it is **native!!!**

Answer (score 5):

AMD  now ship  a desktop OpenGL ES 2.0  version with EGL library
http://developer.amd.com/tools/graphics-development/amd-opengl-es-sdk/

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at Angle Project which brings OpenGL ES to desktops. It works pretty good and not that hard to setup: http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/

Comment: ANGLE is epic, but the build process is actually a pain in the ass on Windows and leads so some errors, which need to be hand-fixed.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL ES is not generally available for Desktop machines. It is intended for embedded systems, hence the name - ES: Embedded  Systems.

Comment: But one doesn't usually use the target embedded platform as their development environment.

Comment: WebGL uses OpenGL ES. So we can buy computers which support native OpenGL ES after 2002.
See also: http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/amd-opengl-es-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a native implementation available (the ES stands for Embedded Systems after all), but you could try ATI's [OpenGL ES Emulator](http://developer.amd.com/GPU/OPENGL/Pages/default.aspx).

edit: 3/3/12 It looks like AMD has discontinued their support of the simulator.

Comment: I should add depending on the platform you are targeting the device vendor likely offers tools to help.

Comment: Thanks the ATI solution appears to be exactly what I'm looking for.